# htmlwebpackPlugin + Maven - how do I manually inject bundled chunkhash files?

Tags: java, maven, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have an issue where Maven + frontend-maven-plugin and webpack doesn't go well together when I install an entire Maven module; Simply put Webpack the htmlwebpackPlugin will not inject the bundled js/css files the first time I install a Maven module, for some reason, even though a template is provided as such:

```
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template : '../resources/public/index.html',
        filename : 'index.html',
        inject : 'body',
    })
```

However if I manually run the `frontend-maven-plugin` after installing the entire Maven module, it will actually inject the correct files, which is rather strange behavior.

To go around this, I wanted to know if there's a manual way to somehow inject these bundled files(I only have three; 1 css, 2 js files) with a chunkhash inside my own `index.html` template? That would make the build much more consistent.

A snip of my `webpack.config.js` - as you can see we add the chunkhash to the filenames if we are not in dev.

```
"use strict";
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


let path = require('path');
let webpack = require("webpack");

const PATHS = {
    build: path.join(__dirname, '../../../target', 'classes', 'public'),
};

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

let isDev = false;

if(env == "dev"){
    isDev = true;
}


console.log(`Dev environment: ${isDev}`);


module.exports = {

    entry: {
        main: './js/index.jsx',
        vendor: [
            "react","react-dom","axios",
            "react-table", "mobx", "mobx-react", "mobx-utils", "lodash"],
    },
    output: {
        path: PATHS.build,
        filename: `bundle.${isDev ? '' : '[chunkhash]'}.js`
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: "vendor", filename: `/static/js/vendor.bundle.${isDev ? '' : '[chunkhash]'}.js`}),
        new ExtractTextPlugin(`/static/css/[name].${isDev ? '' : '[chunkhash]'}.css`),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template : '../resources/public/index.html',
            filename : 'index.html',
            inject : 'body',
        })

    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
    // Bunch of loaders
        ]
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it - the issue was basically that Maven/Spring would take the Index.html(which I used as a template) in `resources/public` outside my target folder and overwrite it in the target folder - basically overwriting the output from `webpackHTMLplugin`, which makes logical sense in this context.

I solved it by not having any `index.html` file in `resources/public`, but just having a `template.html` in the src folder where webpack is. Thereby, it Maven/Spring doesn't overwrite the output with the empty template.